# TrueZip - How to decompress inner jar/zip files without expanding them as directories?

Tags: java, truezip

I'm creating a tzp file using TrueZip 7, and the cp_rp method to add all directory contents at once to the tzp file.

After that, I'm trying to extract all contents of the tzp file to a target directory. However, the call:

```
zipFile = new TFile("test.zip");
public void extract(TFile file){
  for (TFile iFile : zipFile.listFiles()){
    if(iFile.isDirectory()){
       extract(iFile);
    }else{
       File output = new File(iFile.getPath());
       iFile.mv(output);
    }
  }
}
```

Fails with an error: **java.io.IOException: [path]\test.zip\Myjar.jar (destination exists already)**. If I use cp instead of mv, then the error is **[path]\test.zip\Myjar.jar (contained in [path]\test.zip\Myjar.jar)**

The problem also seems to be that TrueZip identifies zips and jars as both directories and archives, so when doing a isDirectory() on them, this succeeds, and doing a listFiles() returns all files contained within, so running a cp() on files recursively causes all jar/zip contents to be copied as directories.

What is the correct way of extracting these archive files without expanding them?

Comment: You realize of course that there's zip support built into the base Java JVM -- java.util.zip.  The pieces are there to allow you to examine zip file contents and extract individual files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extracting an archive file to a directory can be done with one method call:

```
TFile archive = new TFile("archive.zip");
TFile directory = new TFile("directory");
TFile.cp_rp(archive, directory, TArchiveDetector.NULL, TArchiveDetector.NULL);
```

The trick is to use TArchiveDetector.NULL when traversing the directory trees.

Comment: Is there any way to extract one by one? The problem is I need to run some checks on files as I extract them.

Comment: This depends on the type of check. If it's a CRC-32 check, then you could use the CheckedZipDriver instead of the ZipDriver. You wouldn't have to change this code then. Otherwise, you'ld have to do the traversal yourself and use TFile.cp_p(*) instead of TFile.cp_rp(*).

Comment: When I create `TFile directory` using either a `File` object or a String I get the same `IOException`, that the path to the directory is "not a file".