# Split zip with truezip

Tags: java, zip, truezip

Referring to this post I have zipped and unzipped folders successfully - [TrueZip - How to decompress inner jar/zip files without expanding them as directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393090/truezip-how-to-decompress-inner-jar-zip-files-without-expanding-them-as-direct)

Is there any way to split zip into parts using truezip, similar to 7z which allows us to create parts of zip file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, ZIP file splitting/spanning is not supported by TrueZIP.